# Is there any way to catch keypress events in mobile browser keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velo

I built a filter functionality for a list of banks. It works fine in desktop: When the user puts in any name, the keypress event occurs and later it call the `filter()` function.

However, it does not work on mobile, since no keypress event is triggered.

The goal is whenever user put any letter in input filed, it should call that `filter()` function on mobile. Is there any way to do this?

(this website is built on wix so it use its velo api)

```
let debounceTimer;

export function search_keyPress(event) { //enable onKeypress for input form , search is the id of input

$w("#clearSearch").show(); //show the cross mark to clear inputs

$w("#search").value; // value of input field

    if (debounceTimer) {
        clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
        debounceTimer = undefined;
    }

    debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        filter($w("#search").value); //ID of input form
    }, 200);
}

let searchWord;

function filter(search) {
    if (searchWord !== search) {
        $w("#bankTableDataset").setFilter(wixData.filter().contains('bankName', search)); // ID of the dataset
        searchWord = search;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `$w` refers to jquery. then `$w("#search").value` needs to be `$w("#search").val()`

Comment: Use the `input` event instead of keypress? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event

Comment: please check this wix forum discussion: https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/onkeypress-event-key-on-mobile-unidentified

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's not jQuery, it's Velo syntax

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen , its velo syntax used in wix site builder. and  $w = Selects and returns elements from a page